# (Laravel) Database migration updated from another computer, interfering with personal database

Tags: php, sql, git, laravel

I had a migration titled

```
create_iteMs_table.php
```

Not being aware of how important naming conventions were at the time, I kept the 'iteMs' name, and updated the table with later migrations such as

```
add_date_to_iteMs_table.php
```

When the site was deployed, I was informed that we needed to change the name of the iteMs table to 'items'. The migrations were renamed and the database table renamed and pushed to the repo from another computer.

When I made a pull request, the migrations on my local repo were updated with the new 'items' migrations. However, in my personal databse I made the mistake of renaming the 'iteMs' table to 'items' manually. So when I try to run php artisan migrate I get an error saying:

```
Base table or view already exists: 1050 table 'items' already exists
```

I am wondering what the best solution to this is? Would it just involve deleting the 'items' table and running php artisan migrate?

Comment: Or you could a rollback? And then migrate items table again.

Comment: `php artisan migrate:refresh` if you're not worried about any of the data on your personal dev box. This will refresh the whole schema by dropping all tables (and data) and recreating them.